# How to correctly implement LZ4, Snappy or equivalent compression techniques in Java?

Tags: java, compression, snappy, lz4

I've tried implementing Java version of LZ4 into a search engine kind of program trying to search data from large text files. I simply compressed the outputstream and stored it into txt files or files without names. However, I realized the supposedly compressed files did not reduce in size, but it's even larger in size than original files.

At last I had to resort to zip4j since it works for me.

I wonder how may I approach using jars of LZ4 or Snappy to compress/decompress correctly?

In addition, how may I use such algorithms to compress a single folder with many files inside?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try that did not work? Conceptually you simply wrap the FileOutputStream with an OutputStream that provides the compression then write to that stream. If you are writing text, you likely would want to wrap that with an OutputStreamWriter or PrintWriter.   https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.0/snappy-java-1.1.0-javadoc.jar/!/org/xerial/snappy/SnappyFramedOutputStream.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar problem. I was trying to send a large file (~ 709 MB) over local network in chunks of 8192 bytes. I used Lz4 compression/decompression to reduce the network bandwidth.

So assuming you are trying to do something similar, here's my suggestion :

Here's the snippet of similar regular example you'll find on https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java

```
private static int decompressedLength;
private static LZ4Factory factory = LZ4Factory.fastestInstance();
private static LZ4Compressor compressor = factory.fastCompressor();

public static byte[] compress(byte[] src, int srcLen) {
    decompressedLength = srcLen;
    int maxCompressedLength = compressor.maxCompressedLength(decompressedLength);
    byte[] compressed = new byte[maxCompressedLength];
    compressor.compress(src, 0, decompressedLength, compressed, 0, maxCompressedLength);
    return compressed;
}
```

Now if you return the **compressed** byte array as it is then there are fair chances that it may have length greater than the original **uncompressed** data.

So you can modify it as follows :

```
private static int decompressedLength;
private static LZ4Factory factory = LZ4Factory.fastestInstance();
private static LZ4Compressor compressor = factory.fastCompressor();

public static byte[] compress(byte[] src, int srcLen) {
    decompressedLength = srcLen;
    int maxCompressedLength = compressor.maxCompressedLength(decompressedLength);
    byte[] compressed = new byte[maxCompressedLength];
    int compressLen = compressor.compress(src, 0, decompressedLength, compressed, 0, maxCompressedLength);
    byte[] finalCompressedArray = Arrays.copyOf(compressed, compressLen);
    return finalCompressedArray;
}
```

**compressLen** stores the actual compressed length and the **finalCompressedArray** byte array (of length compressLen) stores the actual compressed data. It's length, in general, is less than both the lengths of **compressed**  byte array and original **uncompressed** byte array

Now you can decompress the **finalCompressedArray** byte array in regular fashion as below :

```
private static LZ4FastDecompressor decompressor = factory.fastDecompressor();

public static byte[] decompress(byte[] finalCompressedArray, int decompressedLength) {
    byte[] restored = new byte[decompressedLength];
    restored = decompressor.decompress(finalCompressedArray, decompressedLength);
    return restored;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for acknowledging sooo late!

Comment: @Ankit- If I don't know the size of byte array after decompressing, what will be decompressedLength?

Comment: You have to store it somewhere or transfer as well. Lz4 has example code, it's called something like OutputStreamWithLength, where it stores 4 bytes with uncompressed size first.

Answer (score 1):

A `.jar` file is a `.zip` file.  The zip file format does not support LZ4 or Snappy.

Comment: Oops, wrong question! : P I simply meant how may I use LZ4 or Snappy for compressing large text files